# Assert amount of found nodes greater than N

Tags: capybara

With Capybara, one can easily assert the exact amount of nodes to be found:

```
page.should have_selector("fieldset.has_many_fields input[type=file]", :count => 2)
```

This ensures that there are exactly 2 such fields. But I want to check for "at least 2". Something like:

```
page.all("fieldset.has_many_fields input[type=file]").count should be_greater_than 2
```

This is an example, because it throws `undefined method 'greater_than?' for 3:Fixnum'`

Is there a matcher like this? Or another trick that allows me to check for "at least N nodes"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just have a typo. Try:

```
expect(page.all("fieldset.has_many_fields input[type=file]").count).to be > 2
```

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately the answer from RobertH on 17th Jan 2013 is now depreciated syntax.

For this precise scenario you would need to do:

```
page.all("fieldset.has_many_fields input[type=file]", :minimum => 2)
```

Comment: Clarification: I don't think the referenced answer was using any deprecated _Capybara_ syntax. You can still use `all('…').count` Capybara syntax, just not the `should be`  RSpec syntax in modern versions of RSpec. So you don't _need_ to use this `minimum: 2` way, but it's certainly a valid option as well.

Comment: Good point, although my comment is 2.5 years old now :) Wow time flies lol. But great addition @TylerRick